# Two way data binding in Dart without Angular or Polymer

Tags: dart

How I can do this? I need something like KnockoutJS. I have tried [template_binding](https://github.com/dart-lang/template-binding) but there are no documentation & I can not write working code looking at unit tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template_binding` is a deprecated package and is no longer supported.

Data binding [is a complex topic](https://medium.com/dartlang/building-data-binding-in-the-browser-f523c99de79c) and you're not likely to get something out of the box for free (hence why frameworks like AngularDart, PolymerDart, and OverReact tend to be used for development).